# browserify and coffeescript. Export coffeescript class in window

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, browserify

```
B = require './B.coffee'
class A extends B

window.instanceA = new A
window.A = A
```

Instance of class A becomes available in window, but

```
new window.A()
```

return error *"Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined"*

```
A = (function(_super) {
      __extends(A, _super);

      function A() {
       return A.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
      }

      return A

    })(B);
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: `B` is probably not getting loaded properly, how do you call browserify?

Comment: have you tried `require './B'`?

Comment: No, B loaded success. I can use class A in browserify. But i want use class A outside browserify. if i call "A" as "new A" outside browserify, then have a error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know precisely why you would want to achieve this, but I believe you could export B explicitly?

```
window.B = require './B.coffee'
class A extends window.B

window.instanceA = new A
window.A = A
```